# Downloading activerecord-3.2.14 revealed dependencies not in the API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, bundler

When I am running bundle install, I am getting below issue:

Downloading activerecord-3.2.14 revealed dependencies not in the API (activesupport (= 3.2.14), activemodel (= 3.2.14), arel (~> 3.0.2), tzinfo
(~> 0.3.29)).
Installing with `--full-index` should fix the problem.

Please help me on this.

Comment: As error message says... Do you run `bundle install --full-index`?

Comment: I updated rails version from 3.2.14 to 3.2.16 and bundle ran successfully.
Thanks